# Clima weather app not working it throws LateInitializationError: Field 'latitude' has not been initialized

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Here is the code of my app , please help me with this , it throws an error only the loading screen is working and there is no further progress.

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: LateInitializationError: Field 'latitude' has not been initialized.

E/flutter (24924): #0      Location.latitude (package:clima/services/location.dart)
E/flutter (24924): #1      WeatherModel.getLocationWeather (package:clima/services/weather.dart:23:25)
E/flutter (24924): 
E/flutter (24924): #2      _LoadingScreenState.getLocationData (package:clima/screens/loading_screen.dart:22:23)
E/flutter (24924):

Screens

1. loading screen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:clima/screens/location_screen.dart';
import 'package:clima/services/weather.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';


class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _LoadingScreenState();
  }
}

class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getLocationData();
  }
  void getLocationData() async{
    WeatherModel weatherModel = WeatherModel();
    var weatherData = await weatherModel.getLocationWeather();

    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => LocationScreen(
          locationWeather: weatherData,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SpinKitSpinningLines(
            color: Colors.white,
            size: 50.0,
        ),
      ),
    );


  }
}
```

2. Location screen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:clima/utilities/constants.dart';
import 'package:clima/services/weather.dart';
import 'city_screen.dart';


class LocationScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  LocationScreen({this.locationWeather});

  final locationWeather;
  @override
  _LocationScreenState createState() => _LocationScreenState();
}

class _LocationScreenState extends State<LocationScreen>{

 WeatherModel weather = WeatherModel();

 int temperature = 0;
 String weatherMessage = '0';
 String weatherIcon = '0';
 String cityName = 'jaipur';

 @override
 void initState(){
   super.initState();

   updateUI(widget.locationWeather);
 }

  void updateUI(Future<dynamic> weatherDataFuture)async{
   final weatherData = await weatherDataFuture;
   setState((){
     if(weatherData == null){
       temperature = 0;
       weatherIcon = 'Error';
       weatherMessage = 'Oops an error occurred';
       cityName = '';
       return;

     }
     double temp = weatherData['main']['temp'];
     temperature = temp.toInt();
     var condition = weatherData['weather'][0]['id'];
     weatherIcon = weather.getWeatherIcon(condition);
     weatherMessage = weather.getMessage(temperature);
     cityName = weatherData['name'];
   });


  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: const NetworkImage('https://pixabay.com/photos/clouds-cumulus-sky-nature-2329680/ '),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8), BlendMode.dstATop),
          ),
        ),
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: ()async {
                       var weatherData =  await weather.getLocationWeather();
                       updateUI(weatherData);
                    },
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.near_me,
                      size: 50.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: ()async {
                      var typedName = await Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) {
                        return CityScreen();
                      }
                      )
                      );
                      if(typedName != Null) {
                            var weatherData = await weather.getCityWeather(typedName);
                            updateUI(weatherData);
                          }
                      },
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.location_city,
                      size: 50.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      '32°',
                      style: kTempTextStyle,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '☀️',
                      style: kConditionTextStyle,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0),
                child: Text(
                  "It's  time in San Francisco!",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                  style: kMessageTextStyle,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

3. City screen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:clima/utilities/constants.dart';

class CityScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CityScreenState createState() => _CityScreenState();
}

class _CityScreenState extends State<CityScreen> {

   String cityName = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image:NetworkImage('https://pixabay.com/photos/clouds-sky-bright-daylight-light-1282314/'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, (){
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    });

                  },
                  child: const Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                    size: 50.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
               child:  TextField(
                 style: const TextStyle(
                   color: Colors.black,
                 ),
                 decoration: KTextFieldInputDecoration,
                 onChanged: (value) {
                   cityName = value;
                 },

               ),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context, cityName);
                },
                child: const Text(
                  'Get Weather',
                  style: kButtonTextStyle,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Services

1. location

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class Location{

   late double longitude ;
   late double latitude ;

  Future<void> getCurrentLocation()async{
    try{
      Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low);
      latitude  = position.latitude;
      longitude = position.longitude;
    }
    catch(exception){
      print(exception);
    }
  }

}
```

2. Networking

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class NetworkHelper{

   NetworkHelper(this.url);

   final String url;


   Future getData() async{
     http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

     if(response.statusCode == 200) {
       String data = response.body;

       return jsonDecode(data);
     }
     else{
       print(response.statusCode);
     }

     }
}
```

3. weather

```
import 'package:clima/services/location.dart';
import 'package:clima/services/networking.dart';

const String apiKey = '304dd36c502250baab7c7f8216ec4ff2';
const String openWeatherMapURL = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather';


class WeatherModel {

  Future<dynamic> getCityWeather(String cityName)async {
     NetworkHelper networkHelper = NetworkHelper('$openWeatherMapURL?q=$cityName&appid=$apiKey&units=metric');

     var weatherData = await networkHelper.getData();

     return weatherData;
  }

  Future<dynamic> getLocationWeather()async{
    Location location = Location();
    await location.getCurrentLocation();

    NetworkHelper networkHelper = NetworkHelper('$openWeatherMapURL?lat=${location.latitude}&lon=${location.longitude}&appid=$apiKey&units=metric');

    var weatherData = await networkHelper.getData();

    return weatherData;

  }
  String getWeatherIcon(int condition) {
    if (condition < 300) {
      return '';
    } else if (condition < 400) {
      return '';
    } else if (condition < 600) {
      return '☔️';
    } else if (condition < 700) {
      return '☃️';
    } else if (condition < 800) {
      return '';
    } else if (condition == 800) {
      return '☀️';
    } else if (condition <= 804) {
      return '☁️';
    } else {
      return '‍';
    }
  }

  String getMessage(int temp) {
    if (temp > 25) {
      return 'It\'s  time';
    } else if (temp > 20) {
      return 'Time for shorts and ';
    } else if (temp < 10) {
      return 'You\'ll need  and ';
    } else {
      return 'Bring a  just in case';
    }
  }
}
```

utilites

1. constant

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const kTempTextStyle = TextStyle(
  fontFamily: 'Spartan MB',
  fontSize: 100.0,
);

const kMessageTextStyle = TextStyle(
  fontFamily: 'Spartan MB',
  fontSize: 60.0,
);

const kButtonTextStyle = TextStyle(
  fontSize: 30.0,
  fontFamily: 'Spartan MB',
);

const kConditionTextStyle = TextStyle(
  fontSize: 100.0,
);

const KTextFieldInputDecoration = InputDecoration(
  filled: true,
  fillColor : Colors.white,
  icon: Icon(
    Icons.location_city,
    color: Colors.black,
  ),
  hintText : 'Enter your city name.',
  hintStyle  : TextStyle(
    color: Colors.black,
  ),
  border: OutlineInputBorder(
    borderRadius : BorderRadius.all(
      Radius.circular(5.0),
    ),
    borderSide: BorderSide.none,
  ),
);
```

Comment: If you don't get a result from `Geolocator.getCurrentPosition`, for example if you didn't request position permissions correctly, you never set latitude and longitude since you'll get an exception and skip those lines. Since they're late init, any attempt to read them will fail with at least a similar error as yours.

Answer (score 0):

> Try with this code in Services 1.location

```
   import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
    
    class Location{
    
       double? longitude ;
       double? latitude ;
    
      Future<void> getCurrentLocation()async{
        try{
          Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low);
          latitude  = position.latitude;
          longitude = position.longitude;
        }
        catch(exception){
          print(exception);
        }
      }
    
    }
```

Comment: I tried this and it throws an error      ======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _TypeError was thrown building Builder:
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<dynamic>'